connecting vscode to remote via ssh with agent forwarding when using pageant does not work
I desperately tried to set up vscode remote workspace on a nixos machine using pageant for forwarding ssh keys.
Due to restrictions from my customers, sometimes i only have putty/pageant available (and not the normal ssh-agent on windows)
On the way i tried setting up vscode not using pageant as the forwarded agent, but i never got it to actually forward any keys.
This might be a bug in vscode, but i couldn't figure out via the logs what went wrong.
My current solution is as following:
in vscode inside the settings.json i have:
    "remote.SSH.path": "C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\ssh2plink_64bit.exe",
    "remote.SSH.enableAgentForwarding": true

ssh2plink is a program needed to have vscode use plink from putty when connecting to a remote.
my ssh-config contains:
Host myhost
    HostName x.x.x.x
    User myuser
    ForwardAgent yes

These settings at least allow me to connect to the remote workspace using the key stored in pageant. But requesting stored identities via
ssh-add -L

only tells me there are no identities (which means the pageant is not connected)
my current workaround is to start up my fish shell, where pageant and agent-forwarding works properly by simply using
ssh -A myuser@myhost

this will then create some ssh socket in
/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXXX/agent.xxxxxx

then in vscode terminal (which is already connected to the remote) i use
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(ls -t /tmp/ssh-**/* | head -1)

which sets the ssh auth sock to the socket that i had previously created using my fish. ssh-add -L now shows the available keys properly.
This is a nice workaround for now, but i'd rather have my vscode set up the pageant forwarding properly.
Does anyone have a clue on how to get that to work the way one would whish?
EDIT: Just in case someone needs this: in order to use pageant with vscode remote connection, there must be a change in the automatically created pageant.conf file. Otherwise, vscode console would error that includes cant be outside of host section and fail the connection. I therefore changed my start_pageant.bat in my autostart this way:
Start "" pageant.exe --openssh-config %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\pageant.conf --encrypted %USERPROFILE%\path\to\privkey.ppk
timeout /t 2
SET "configfile=%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\pageant.conf"
set /p configcontent=<%configfile%
SET "text=Host *"
:: copy the contents into a temp file
type %configfile%> temp.txt
:: Now Overwrite the file with the contents in "configcontent" variable
echo %text%> %configfile%
:: Add a tab character before IdentityAgent
echo(   %configcontent%>> %configfile%
:: Delete the temporary file
del temp.txt

the tab character might be not properly copied, so you might have to correct that
echo(ENTER_HERE_TAB_CHAR_VIA_KEYBOARD%configcontent%>> %configfile%
